# Google chrome high hard disk usage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, google-chrome, performance, browser

I'm on Windows 7 from boot to VHD. I got a lot of RAM and my pagefile is disabled. This OS can be up for days, even up to 3-4 weeks of working time without restart. I put it to sleep\suspend quite often. I do not know if this is relevant.

I use Google Chrome and I open many windows with many tabs on each window, so it can go up to 100 or more tabs left open for days sometimes. Chrome can consume large amounts of memory for this, so 5 or 8 GB of RAM just for Chrome is usual, but there is still plenty of RAM left free.

The problem is that Chrome is massively using hard drive, even when I do not use it. It can 
do it for minutes which makes computer sluggish. Then when I want to open new page it stops sometimes without response, so I need to wait until all disk work is done. From what I figured out read \ writes are mainly to: $Logfile, Jumplisticons, Cache, temp, local storage, so most of it in Chromes User Data directory. Even now I'm just writing this and there is like 30 files that Chrome need to write to and I see constant disk usage.

Is this some kind of bug ? Can I configure it somehow to work as it should ? (I do not want to disable functionality, just to make it work fast)

EDIT:

I figured out some more of this. This read\write operations are mainly in

> C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
>   Data\Default\JumpListIcons

Chrome just keep creating small files there named like 1ABC.tmp then move them to JumpListIconsOld directory then remove them straight away.

Comment: That's a lot of tabs. Have you had success with any other browser? Also, some sites seem to use a lot of resources just sitting there. You can use Chrome's task manager to see if there are any specific tabs acting badly.

Comment: @fooot: ye its quite a few. its usually more like 200-300. interesting tool, didnt know about it. i will observe this as well, but there is nothing about disk usage. i didnt try other browser on this setup, but i will have to do it.

Comment: follow this (http://pastebin.com/AyxAVU60) and give me the ETL file. With it I can see which File and DISK IO Chrome does.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is a bug reported 4 years ago.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40407

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=179576